# WCF Client adds namespace to XML before parsing

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-client

I'm currently implementing a WCF Client app which consumes a Java webservice that uses SOAP as the communication protocol. I generated a proxy from the WSDL provided by the server and when I make calls everything runs through without an error but the received list contains no elements.

I've looked at the incoming XML with Wireshark and WCF tracing/message logging and therefore can be certain that I do receive the intended data. But it seams that the WCF Client somehow manipulates the XML before parsing by inserting an empty namespace  which prevents the deserializer from creating the objects from the xml.

**Wireshark**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:ns="stat">
    <ns:mt_getStation>
      <ROW>
        <Station_ID>96</Station_ID>
        <Station>Station Test</Station>
        <Timestamp>2014-09-15T14:00:35</Timestamp>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <Station_ID>42</Station_ID>
        <Station>Answer Station Test</Station>
        <Timestamp>2014-09-15T14:00:35</Timestamp>
      </ROW>
    </ns:mt_getStation>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**WCF Message log**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:ns="stat">
    <ns:mt_getStation>
      <ROW xmlns="">
        <Station_ID>96</Station_ID>
        <Station>Station Test</Station>
        <Timestamp>2014-09-15T14:00:35</Timestamp>
      </ROW>
      <ROW xmlns="">
        <Station_ID>42</Station_ID>
        <Station>Answer Station Test</Station>
        <Timestamp>2014-09-15T14:00:35</Timestamp>
      </ROW>
    </ns:mt_getStation>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I prevent the WCF client from inserting the empty namespaces?